# JS Script Returning Undefined Instead of Expected String

Tags: javascript

I basically have been making a program that will go through a website and grab certain images. This is not *too* hard, just a little complex. I was running the JS code below to click onto the correct page, check for the gallery element to load every 100ms, then finally log the entire object as a string. Most works, but when getting the `console.log(...);` I get undefined as the main return, and I get the string afterwards as a secondary. This will not due because my program can only intercept the main logged value, not any secondaries. Below is my code and an example output. Thank you!

Code:

```
document.getElementById('tlcItem_47871').click();
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.pgFooterThumblist').length) {
        clearInterval(checkExist);
        var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('pgFooterThumb');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ele));
    }
}, 100);
```

Ex Output:

```
/*Primary Output(First)*/<- undefined
/*Secondary Output(Second)*/<- {"0":{},"1":{},"2":{},"3":{},"4":{},"5":{},"6":{},"7":{},"8":{},"9":{},"10":{},"11":{},"12":{},"13":{},"14":{},"15":{},"16":{},"17":{},"18":{},"19":{},"20":{},"21":{},"22":{},"23":{},"24":{},"25":{},"26":{},"27":{},"28":{},"29":{},"30":{},"31":{},"32":{},"33":{},"34":{},"35":{},"36":{},"37":{},"38":{},"39":{},"40":{},"41":{},"42":{},"43":{},"44":{},"45":{},"46":{},"47":{},"48":{},"49":{},"50":{},"51":{},"52":{},"53":{},"54":{},"55":{},"56":{},"57":{},"58":{},"59":{},"60":{},"61":{},"62":{},"63":{},"64":{},"65":{},"66":{},"67":{},"68":{},"69":{},"70":{},"71":{},"72":{},"73":{},"74":{},"75":{},"76":{},"77":{},"78":{},"79":{},"80":{},"81":{},"82":{},"83":{},"84":{},"85":{},"86":{},"87":{},"88":{},"89":{},"90":{},"91":{},"92":{},"93":{},"94":{},"95":{},"96":{},"97":{},"98":{},"99":{},"100":{},"101":{},"102":{},"103":{},"104":{},"105":{},"106":{},"107":{},"108":{},"109":{},"110":{},"111":{},"112":{},"113":{},"114":{},"115":{},"116":{},"117":{},"118":{},"119":{},"120":{},"121":{},"122":{},"123":{},"124":{},"125":{},"126":{},"127":{},"128":{},"129":{},"130":{},"131":{},"132":{},"133":{},"134":{},"135":{},"136":{},"137":{},"138":{},"139":{},"140":{},"141":{},"142":{},"143":{},"144":{},"145":{},"146":{},"147":{},"148":{},"149":{},"150":{},"151":{},"152":{},"153":{},"154":{},"155":{},"156":{},"157":{},"158":{},"159":{},"160":{},"161":{},"162":{},"163":{},"164":{},"165":{},"166":{},"167":{},"168":{},"169":{},"170":{},"171":{},"172":{},"173":{},"174":{},"175":{},"176":{},"177":{},"178":{},"179":{},"180":{},"181":{},"182":{},"183":{},"184":{},"185":{},"186":{},"187":{},"188":{},"189":{},"190":{},"191":{},"192":{},"193":{},"194":{},"195":{},"196":{},"197":{},"198":{},"199":{},"200":{},"201":{},"202":{},"203":{},"204":{},"205":{},"206":{},"207":{},"208":{},"209":{},"210":{},"211":{},"212":{},"213":{},"214":{},"215":{},"216":{},"217":{},"218":{},"219":{}}
```

EDIT: In the workflow that I have I am able to set my JS script in my c++, and then I can run javascript into a loaded webpage. The only issue is that the `runJavascript()` function will take the first value outputted and use that. No way around it so I need the string to be outputted ASAP.

Comment: I assume you're entering this into the console? It's normal for a command to return undefined.

Comment: I feel like I don't fully understand your issue-- you just need it to not console log for undefined values?  What is required?

Comment: @JaromandaX This is the output that i see first in the console & the one my program interprets.

Comment: @E.Sundin nailed it

Comment: @E.Sundin Any way to return my string before undefined?

Comment: If all you need is to prevent undefined console logs, you can save JSON.stringify to a var, and then check to see if it is undefined before you do anything with it (like console logging).  And @E.Sundin is probably correct-- you're probably looking for `return`.

Comment: @NicholasJohnson `var a = "a"` also returns `undefined`. Why would you want that though? The `undefined` return isn't a problem in itself, if it's a problem for you then specify why that is.

Comment: @E.Sundin Just made an edit.

Comment: So your C code is intercepting whatever is logged to the console?

Comment: @anied Sorta, I'll look how it is documented.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS NOT A CORRECT ANSWER.  I AM LEAVING IT FOR CONTEXT ONLY.**

Assuming that *all* that is need is to avoid console logging an undefined value, this would suffice:

```
document.getElementById('tlcItem_47871').click();
var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    if ($('.pgFooterThumblist').length) {
        clearInterval(checkExist);
        var ele = document.getElementsByClassName('pgFooterThumb');
        var loggedOutput = JSON.stringify(ele);
        if (loggedOutput) {
            console.log(loggedOutput);
        }
    }
}, 100);
```

This is assuming that somehow your C code intercepts this console log.  Generally in JavaScript if you need a value from a function you need to pass it back to the caller using a `return` statement, but it seems that perhaps you have a unique case in which this is not required.

Comment: Just tested, first value logged is still `undefined`

Comment: OK, then this is not the answer for you-- there may be more going on under the hood here than meets the eye.

Comment: Thank you very mush for trying!